# Probability of Having two event overlapping each other

Tags: probability

On a timeline of one full day, we want to to find the probability of occurring overlaps of two signal. 
One single is being generated every second and exist for 1 microsecond. The another signal is generated randomly with a 1KHz frequency with 50% duty cycle. Or i can say this is randomly coming at stay for 500 microsecond high and 500 microsecond low.

We now need to find a probability that these both signal overlap each other for 35 seconds in a row. it means the probability of having 2nd signal high when the 1st signal is generated for 35 incidents in a row in whole day.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No, it is a problem we are facing in a solving a problem. We need to fins the probability so that we can design the solution to handle this exception.

Comment: So the duration of the random signal is fixed at 500 microsec high and 500 microsec low. The starting time of this 1000 microsec signal is what is random. Is that correct?

Comment: 1 usec signal is assumed on start of each second however the 2nd signal of 500 usec is completely random and distributed in a second. Next second again it will be random and can start at any moment and not in sync with last second (Actually this is uncontrolled noise signal where anything thing can come at high frequency. For simplicity it is assumed as 1Khz ). Now the probability having both signal high in 1 second to be calculated and then probability of having a sequence of 35 incident in a row to calculated. Ultimate objective is "How many time a day / month this situation will occur"

Comment: The problem is that even there will be low probability of this, we have to calculate the number of expected failure in a month if 10 million product are in field.